# ASP.Net c# - How do I instantiate an instance of a WebUserControl from within a App_Code class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

Aloha,

I have a custom control that I need to instantiate from within a class and add to a page. My class has a function that I pass the `Page` to so i have access to the controls on the page. I'm using this method to add standard ASP controls already and everything it working as expected. My problem is that the type for the custom control is know defined?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182984/asp-net-instantiate-a-web-user-control-in-app-code-class) to move the .cs from the control into the App_Code folder but when I do that it won't compile as it doesn't see the controls in the ascx as valid. For example I get `CS0103: The name 'litTest' does not exist in the current context`. So as they are partial classes I created a new empty partial class in the App_Code folder and left the control's .cs file alone.

Well it compiles this way but when I add the control to the Page.controls collection, I dont see anything on the page where it should be. For example I added `TEST` to the bottom of the ascx file, it I dont see it on the page. Additionally the control has variables that I need to set that I don't have access to when using the empty partial class.

I know that what I am trying to do works with standard controls, why can't I seem to make this work with a custom control?

**My partial class in the App_Code folder:**

```
public partial class CustomControlClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

}
```

**My partial class in for the user control:**

```
public partial class CustomControlClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private int _myValue= -1;
    public int myValue
    {
        get { return _myValue; }
        set { _myValue= value; }
    }
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        litTest.Text = "TEST";
    }
}
```

**My user control ascx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CustomControlClass.ascx.cs" Inherits="CustomControlClass" %>
<asp:Literal ID="litTest" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
TEST
```

**My App_Code class:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void doWork(Page Ctrl)
    {
        CustomControlClass c = new CustomControlClass();
        //c.myValue = 1;  // Wont compile with this line
        Ctrl.Controls.Add(c);

        Literal l = new Literal();
        l.Text = "HELLO";
        Ctrl.Controls.Add(l);
    }
}
```

The page output does not have the word TEST on it at all. The word HELLO shows up just fine. I've tried calling the `MyClass.doWork()` from the pages `Load`, `Init` and `PreInit` callbacks, all result in the dame thing.

**Update:**

As *Minh Nguyen* suggested I can use `Ctrl.LoadControl("~/Controls/CustomControlClass.ascx");` to load the control but I can not cast it as its own type I have to assign it as a Control type:

```
Control c= Ctrl.LoadControl("~/Controls/CustomControlClass.ascx");
```

Doing this will let me add the control to the page and have it work as expected. The down side is that I have no access to any of the controls properties. To solve this i am doing this:

```
c.GetType().GetProperty("myValue").SetValue(c, 1, null);
```

This works, but I'm not sure how expensive that it to use. I wish I could just cast the control but I get an error when I try.

I'm leaving this unanswered for a bit to see if there are any other options.

Comment: is your page properly place on the default.aspx page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
CustomControlClass c = (CustomControlClass)Ctrl.LoadControl("~/VirtualPathToASCX/CustomControlClass.ascx");
```

instead of

```
CustomControlClass c = new CustomControlClass();
```

**UPDATE:** fix cast bug

```
//LoadControl
ASP.customcontrolclass_ascx c = (ASP.customcontrolclass_ascx)this.LoadControl("~/Controls/CustomControlClass.ascx");
//set myValue
c.myValue = 3;
```

you can't see ASP.customcontrolclass_ascx type in VS AutoComplete List but it compiled with no error.

Comment: This is closer! I get "Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.customcontrolclass_ascx' to type 'CustomControlClass'." If i use Control as the type it get added to the page, and I see the word TEST but I can not set myValue.

Comment: When I try to use ASP.custoncontrolclass_ascx i get " CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ASP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"  Not sure what reference i would need to add to get the ASP namespace working.

Comment: Same to you, i got this message too. But ignore it, i try building website and it was compiled successfully. (I use VS2008 with .Net FrameWork 3.5 sp1)

Answer (score 1):

not sure what's going on with your code, but using *mostly* what you showed works for me:

**~/controls/testControl.ascx**:

```
<%@ Control Language='C#' AutoEventWireup='false' 
  Inherits='CustomControlClass' 
%>
<asp:Literal ID='litTest' runat='server'></asp:Literal>
```

**.aspx page**:

```
<%@ Page Language='C#' %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<script runat='server'>
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnInit(e);
  MyClass.doWork(this.Page);
}
</script>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head runat='server'><title></title></head>
<body><form id='form1' runat='server'>
</form></body></html>
```

**~/app_code/CustomControlClass.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class CustomControlClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
  private int _myValue= -1;
  public int myValue {
    get { return _myValue; }
    set { _myValue= value; }
  }
  private Literal _litTest;
  public Literal litTest {
    get { return _litTest; }
    set { _litTest= value; }

  }
  protected override void  OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnInit(e);
    litTest.Text = "TEST";
  }
}
```

**~/app_code/MyClass**:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class MyClass {
  public static void doWork(Page Ctrl) {
    CustomControlClass c = 
      (CustomControlClass) Ctrl.LoadControl("~/controls/testControl.ascx");
    c.myValue = 1;
    Ctrl.Form.Controls.Add(c);

    Literal l = new Literal();
    l.Text = string.Format(
      "<p>CustomControlClass.myValue: {0} </p>", 
      c.myValue
    )
    + string.Format(
      "<p>CustomControlClass.litTest.Text: {0} </p>", 
      c.litTest.Text
    )
    ;
    Ctrl.Form.Controls.Add(l);
  }
}
```

in other words the cast to **CustomControlClass** when calling **LoadControl()** works for me. if i understood you correctly that's the problem?

Comment: Yup, the cast is not working for me I get the "Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.customcontrolclass_ascx' to type 'CustomControlClass'." error when i try to. I've currently solved this with reflection but the just seems overkill to get the job done.

Comment: i tested the code above _before_ i posted. it works without problem, including the cast. would you try it?

Answer (score 1):

A different way of LoadControl which works (only .NET 4 tested)

Usage is as follows in any page you can call

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = SomeClass.GetNewUserControl( "hello add me");

    Panel1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
}
```

**~/app_code/BaseMyControls.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for BaseMyControls
/// </summary>
public class BaseMyControls  : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string strProperty;

    public BaseMyControls()
    {

    }
}
```

**~/app_code/SomeClassInApp_Code.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for SomeClassInApp_Code
/// </summary>
public class SomeClassInApp_Code
{
    public static System.Web.UI.Control GetNewUserControl(string someString)
    {
        BaseMyControls bc = (BaseMyControls)(new System.Web.UI.UserControl()).LoadControl("~/controls/MyUC.ascx");
        bc.strProperty = someString;
        return bc;
    }
}
```

**~/controls/MyUC.aspx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyUC.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyUC" %>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" /></asp:Label>
```

**~/controls/MyUC.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class MyUC : BaseMyControls
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = this.strProperty;

        lbl.Text = a;
    }
}
```